# Combining javascript and jquery to fill multiple hidden fields - bad idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, powerschool

I'm trying to find the best way to make my teachers' lives a little easier.

I've got a select field and list of options generated by a tlist sql query. The select field itself already has a javascript attached to it, which fleshes out other field values (credit values and credit types) elsewhere  based on the id of the select option chosen.  This is the javascript that works for that purpose:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(){

    var option=document.getElementById('courseno').value;
    if(option=="E100"){
            document.getElementById('credval').value="10";
            document.getElementById('credtype').value="EngFresh";
    }
        else if(option=="E200"){
            document.getElementById('credval').value="10";
            document.getElementById('credtype').value="EngSoph";
        }

}
 </script>
```

I also need to populate a hidden field that is (and must remain) outside the tlist sql tag that generates the select list.

Here is my sql code:

```
<select id="courseno" name="course_number" onchange="changeValue();">
<option value="">Select a Course</option>
~[tlist_sql;
     SELECT cc.course_number, cc.section_number, c.COURSE_NAME  
     FROM cc cc
     RIGHT JOIN COURSES c ON c.COURSE_NUMBER = cc.course_number
     RIGHT JOIN STUDENTS s ON cc.studentid = s.id 
     WHERE cc.studentid = ~(curstudid)
     AND TERMID = ~(curtermid)
     AND c.CreditType LIKE 'English%'
     AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM storedgrades sg
          WHERE sg.studentid = ~(curstudid)
          AND sg.course_number = c.course_number
                    )
     ORDER BY c.course_name;]
<option name="~(course_no)" value="~(course_no)" id="~(secno)">~(course_no).~(secno) (~(cname))</option>

        [/tlist_sql]

        </select></td>
    </tr>
```

And just below that is the hidden field I would like to populate:

```
<td width="25%" class="bold">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="secnum" name="section_number" value=""> </td>
```

I gave each of the options the section number as its ID, thinking I could use the ID element of each of those options and some clever jquery to populate the hidden field, but I'm having no luck.  I just read on another question that was ably answered by the community that you shouldn't use an option ID tag that begins with a number... so now what can I do?

Could somebody please help me?

Thanks forever,
Schelly

Comment: Plot twist: jQuery **is** Javascript.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli *gasp* you forgot to use the spoiler tag! :X

Comment: @Kritner And that's why I wish comments had an edit button xP

Comment: Append some text to your id, like "id12345". Also, your solution is rife with SQL Injection attack vectors.

Comment: is this using PowerSchool? As a developer with a lot of JavaScript and jQuery experience, I read this question and have no idea how to proceed, because what you're showing, with "tlist_sql" embedded inside HTML, isn't standard outside of whatever framework you're using (this is also probably why the comments above are mostly snarky). And a Google search suggests it would be PowerSchool. If that's the case, I'd suggest adding the PowerSchool tag.

Comment: PowerSchool, if that's what it is, looks like anti-MVC city!

Comment: To answer the headline question: no, it's not a bad idea to write jQuery and (other) JavaScript, but it's important to know that jQ IS JavaScript, because otherwise it can be very hard to figure out what order things will happen. I think I can guess how the tlist_SQL works, and that JDB has the right idea. Can you add your best-guess jQuery code to the question, if JDB's "answer" isn't enough?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - sorry I'm such a newbie - still learning.  Thank you for kindly adding to my knowledgebase.

Comment: @JDB, I'm suitably alarmed - where can I find solutions to my Vector, Victor?  (ok, admittedly that's an obscure reference...)

Comment: @kcrumley - thank you so much, yes - it's PS, and there isn't any PS tag for the section number just like that.  I'm able to create the sql-generated select list and obtain the section number, but I have no earthly idea of how to get the resultant section number into a field outside of the select list options.  I'm 100% open to any kind of ideas you might have.

Comment: re: SQL injection, I'd suspect that PowerSchool handles those issues when it preprocesses the tlist_sql blocks. I doubt "; DROP TABLE ..." is a value of ~(curstudid) that would be accepted, but I have no actual knowledge of PS. OK, I think I finally understand what you actually want to do here, and I'm going to write up an answer.

Comment: No - using database record IDs in your query is an easy path toward hacking. I could easily modify the HTML form to request different IDs, and that way I could step through all of the student records. You should not output database record IDs to your HTML. You should replace them with temporary IDs or use some sort of validation to guarantee that the user requesting those records has permission to view them.

Comment: Hi JDB - I think I understand.  I'm not sure this is any better, but it's true - the ~(curstudid) call gets an ID number that is not the record number.  It's simply an identifier - does that make a difference in your warning?

Comment: JDB, that's forceful browsing, not SQL injection, and it's quite common for frameworks to handle those issues by a pre-query filtering by permissions, or by any number of ways to validate that a request falls within expected limits. Or to not worry about it at all, for LOB systems with a limited number of trusted users. When users are employees, have to be authenticated, and know every request in the system is logged, they tend not to do a lot of things that will get them fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem comes from the ID being a number. We haven't seen what jQuery you've tried, but you most likely don't need jQuery at all. Assuming what you have is working correctly, and the PowerSchool code is putting out  elements the way you expect them to be (View Source in your browser to be sure, if this doesn't work), you should be able to grab the ID from the selected option inside your changeValue function, store it in a variable, and push that value into the "secnum" field as follows:

```
function changeValue(){
    var courseDropdown = document.getElementById('courseno');
    var selectedElement=courseDropdown.options[courseDropdown.selectedIndex];
    var option=selectedElement.value;
    var courseNo = selectedElement.getAttribute("id");
    if(option=="E100"){
        document.getElementById('credval').value="10";
        document.getElementById('credtype').value="EngFresh";
    }
    else if(option=="E200"){
        document.getElementById('credval').value="10";
        document.getElementById('credtype').value="EngSoph";
    }

   document.getElementById('secnum').value=courseNo;
```

}

I changed the way that your "option" variable is being set, but it will work the same way. You might end up wanting to move the last line, where the "secnum" field is being set, or wrap it in an "if", etc.; I don't know your full requirements.

All that said, there would be nothing wrong with using jQuery in this situation, but it's not necessary in this case unless you need extreme backwards-browser compatibility.

Comment: Hi kcrumley - the javascript functions the way it did before with the credval and credtype, but I put in the document.getElementById('secnum') line right before the last } and I'm still not getting a value on that input field.

Comment: can you View Source, and paste in 2-3 of the <option> tags that appear inside your <select>?

Comment: <select id="courseno" name="course_number" onchange="changeValue();">
<option value="">Select a Course</option>



<option name="E300" value="E300" data-number="7">E300.7 (English 11)</option>

  


<option name="E400" value="E400" data-number="7">E400.7 (English 12)</option>

  
  </select>



</td>
 </tr>
  <td width="25%" class="bold">Section Number**: </td>
  <td>
                 <input type="text" id="secnum" name="section_number">

Comment: hmm, the "id" attribute isn't coming through on those <option> tags at all. It doesn't appear that '<option name="~(course_no)" value="~(course_no)" id="~(secno)">' is doing what you want it to do, right?

Comment: d0h!  That was it - I forgot to change the data-number back to id.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Working Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1hcv7gb6/2/)

You can use multiple on change events to do whatever you want. On change add a new event and populate the hidden input. You can define custom attributes to any html element with any data that is required to populate the hidden input

```
<select id="myselect">
<option>Select</option>
<option data-number="1">One</option>
<option data-number="2">Two</option>
<option data-number="3">Three</option>
<option data-number="4">Four</option>
<option data-number="5">Five</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myselect').on('change', mySelectChange);
function mySelectChange(){
    console.log('your standard change value  here');
}
$('#myselect').on('change', mySelectChange2);
function mySelectChange2(){
    var option = $("#myselect option:selected");               
    console.log(option.text());
    console.log(option.attr('data-number'));
}});
```

Comment: Hi Sapphire, could you explain "console.log(option.text()" to me?  I'm not at all familiar with how to use that.  Also, thank you for the new attribute "data-number" - I've never seen that used anywhere.  I'm anxious to try your solution, I'm very appreciative of your time and expertise.

Comment: console.log is a simple logging statement to log that is passed to that function. You can use developer tools to see the actual output. I added that to just test my solution. You can simply replace that statement with the below line  $('#hiddenInput').val(option.attr('data-number'));

Comment: Hi Sapphire - I meant to thank you for teaching me new stuff, too.  I really appreciate that you jumped in with your code and your patience.  Thank you.